JMeter Constant Throughput Timer Not Reaching Desired TPS
I have a JMeter test plan with a dummy sampler and a Constant Throughput Timer added as its child. I want to achieve a target of 10 TPS, so I set the throughput to 600 samples per minute, Users - 10. However, after running the test, I expected it to reach 10 TPS, but it’s not performing as expected. Can someone help me identify what I might be doing wrong?
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.6.3">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <Arguments guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
          <elementProp name="TPM_TO_ACHIEVE" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">TPM_TO_ACHIEVE</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(TPM_TO_ACHIEVE,600.0)}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="TOTALDURATION" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">TOTALDURATION</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(sz_duration,60)}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="API_Invoked" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">API_Invoked</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">true</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
        </collectionProp>
      </Arguments>
      <hashTree/>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group">
        <intProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">10</intProp>
        <intProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">10</intProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration">${TOTALDURATION}</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">true</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">true</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller">
          <intProp name="LoopController.loops">-1</intProp>
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
        </elementProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <IfController guiclass="IfControllerPanel" testclass="IfController" testname="If Controller">
          <boolProp name="IfController.evaluateAll">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="IfController.useExpression">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="IfController.condition">&quot;${API_Invoked}&quot;==&quot;true&quot;</stringProp>
        </IfController>
        <hashTree>
          <kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler guiclass="kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySamplerGui" testclass="kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler" testname="jp@gc - Dummy Sampler">
            <boolProp name="WAITING">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="SUCCESFULL">true</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="RESPONSE_CODE">200</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RESPONSE_MESSAGE">OK</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="REQUEST_DATA">Dummy Sampler used to simulate requests and responses
without actual network activity. This helps debugging tests.</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RESPONSE_DATA">Dummy Sampler used to simulate requests and responses
without actual network activity. This helps debugging tests.</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RESPONSE_TIME">${__Random(50,500)}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="LATENCY">${__Random(1,50)}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="CONNECT">${__Random(1,5)}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="URL"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RESULT_CLASS">org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult</stringProp>
          </kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler>
          <hashTree>
            <ConstantThroughputTimer guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="ConstantThroughputTimer" testname="Constant Throughput Timer">
              <stringProp name="throughput">${TPM_TO_ACHIEVE}</stringProp>
              <intProp name="calcMode">2</intProp>
            </ConstantThroughputTimer>
            <hashTree/>
          </hashTree>
        </hashTree>
        <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">true</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>true</assertions>
              <subresults>true</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>false</xml>
              <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
              <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
              <url>true</url>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
              <idleTime>true</idleTime>
              <connectTime>true</connectTime>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
        </ResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
        <kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector guiclass="kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.TransactionsPerSecondGui" testclass="kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector" testname="jp@gc - Transactions per Second">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>true</assertions>
              <subresults>true</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>false</xml>
              <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
              <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
              <url>true</url>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
              <idleTime>true</idleTime>
              <connectTime>true</connectTime>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
          <longProp name="interval_grouping">1000</longProp>
          <boolProp name="graph_aggregated">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="include_sample_labels"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="exclude_sample_labels"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="start_offset"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="end_offset"></stringProp>
          <boolProp name="include_checkbox_state">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="exclude_checkbox_state">false</boolProp>
        </kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
        <ResultCollector guiclass="StatVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="Aggregate Report">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>true</assertions>
              <subresults>true</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>false</xml>
              <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
              <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
              <url>true</url>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
              <idleTime>true</idleTime>
              <connectTime>true</connectTime>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
        </ResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>



Average response time is 276 milliseconds, it means that I user can make 3.62 requests per second, 10 users will make 36 requests per second.
If you need 600 requests per second you will need to increase the number of to 166+
You can also take a look at Throughput Shaping Timer and Concurrency Thread Group combination, they can be connected together via Feedback function, this way JMeter will be able to kick off extra threads if the current amount is not enough to achieve the desired throughput.
